# Mocha runs only one test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, sails.js, mocha.js

I have a sails.js app that I want to test with mocha, in my test folder I have 2 tests, but when I run mocha only one test gets executed.

Test1.js

```
var request = require('supertest');

describe.only('UserController', function() {

  describe('#login()', function() {
    it('should redirect to /mypage', function (done) {
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Test2.js

```
describe.only('UsersModel', function() {

  describe('#find()', function() {
    it('should check find function', function (done) {
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

I run tests with this command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha
```

Output

```
UserController
  #login()
    ✓ should redirect to /mypage 


1 passing (10ms)
```

Please explain me my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are running an exclusive test by using `describe.only()`. Use `describe()` instead.

See [exclusive tests](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#exclusive-tests) in the mocha documentation